# How to change the search icon color when the user hovers the search input?

Tags: html, css

Do you know how to change the search icon color from gray to black when the user hovers the search input? With the code below the search icon only cahnges the color from gray to black when the user hover the search icon and not when the user hovers the search input.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/83vnj5ru/8/

HTML:

```css
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.input-group-text {
  color: gray;
}

.input-group-text:hover {
  color: black;
}

.filters {
  display: inline-block;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.filters i {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.search {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.search-icon {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  border: 1px solid white !important;
}

.search-input {
  border: 2px solid white !important;
}

.search-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: gray !important;
}

.search-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: gray;
}

.search-input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: gray;
}

.search-input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: gray;
}

.search:hover {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
  color: gray;
}

.search-input:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: black !important;
}

.search-input:hover:-moz-placeholder {
  color: black;
}

.search-input:hover::-moz-placeholder {
  color: black;
}

.search-input:hover:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-toggle:hover {
  color: black !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="bg-custom-gray-dark">
  <div class="container py-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item bg-custom-light2 py-4">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <form class="col-5">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group search">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text search-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control search-input p-0" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Search...">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>

              <div class="col-7 text-right">
                <div class="dropdown filters mr-3">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Filter 1 <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                      </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown filters">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Filter 2 <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                      </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.search:hover` to change the child elements when `.search` is hovered over. In this case it would be:

```
.search:hover .input-group-text {
    color: black;
}
```

```css
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.input-group-text {
  color: gray;
}

.input-group-text:hover {
  color: black;
}

.search:hover .input-group-text {
  color: black;
}

.filters {
  display: inline-block;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.filters i{
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.search{
  border:2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.search-icon {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  border: 1px solid white !important;
}

.search-input {
  border: 2px solid white !important;
}

.search-input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color: gray !important;
}

.search-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: gray;
}

.search-input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: gray;
}

.search-input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: gray;
}



.search:hover{
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
  color: gray;
}

.search:hover .search-input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color: black !important;
}

.search:hover .search-input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: black;
}

.search:hover .search-input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: black;
}

.search:hover .search-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: black;
}


.dropdown-toggle:hover{
  color:black !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="bg-custom-gray-dark">
  <div class="container py-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item bg-custom-light2 py-4">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <form class="col-5">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group search">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text search-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control search-input p-0"
                           id="exampleInputEmail1"
                           aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Search...">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>

              <div class="col-7 text-right">
                <div class="dropdown filters mr-3">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"
                     aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Filter 1 <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown filters">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"
                     aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Filter 2 <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parent `div` with class `search` and when it is hovered change the color of the icon:

```
.input-group.search:hover .fa-search {
    color: black;
}
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/83vnj5ru/8/) an updated fiddle